# Hbase is not starting in cloudera hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

Service did not start successfully while starting the Hbase master.  Not all the required roles started.  Service has only 0 master roles running instead of minimum required 1 for Hbase in cloudera hadoop CDH5.3

A few months back, it worked fine.  will the corrupted blocks in hdfs affect hbase while starting?

Comment: what is the exact error? any log?

Comment: Yes, the corrupted blocks will cause the hbase to not start properly if those belong to `/hbase` hdfs location